# ajaxSubmitButton beforeSend add vars to request

Tags: ajax, yii

I have **ajaxSubmitButton** with **beforeSend** option:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('', CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('site/index')), 
    array(
        'dataType'=>'json',
        'data'=>'js:jQuery(this).parents("form").serialize()',
        'beforeSend'=>'js:function(data){
            // myArr is "good" array for param
            myData =$.param(myArr);
            /** SOMETHIG TO DO **/
        }',             

    )
);
```

So how can I add **myData** to request data and send it with post request?

Comment: Can you a (hidden) form field that contains myData?

Comment: Yes, but leave that for last solution. And there are big question does `jQuery(this).parents("form").serialize()` generated before `beforeSend` call or after.

Comment: @IvoRenkema as I afraid code takes form data before `beforeSend` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier than I expect, just need to create function what returns my params:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getMyData(){
    return $.param(myArr);
}
</script>
```

And then concatenate it with data:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('', CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('site/index')), 
    array(
        'dataType'=>'json',
        'data'=>'js:jQuery(this).parents("form").serialize()+"&"+getMyData()',
        'beforeSend'=>'js:function(data){
        }',             

    )
);
```